# R_USER MashUp with Python and R

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, environment-variables, rpy2

I've been trying to embed R within Python using rpy2. The installation of rpy2 by setting the R_USER during installation worked fine and some code execution with native packages of R worked like charm.

However, I'm encountering some issues when trying to call some additional packages of R like ggplot2 through Python. It seems like by changing the default R_USER after the rpy2 installation Python is able to work through rpy2 properly, but R is not able to find its user libraries anymore. It has to be something I'm missing cause when launching an R-session through RStudio, R is able to find its libraries again.

So basically I'm having this:

Changing environment variable for R_USER:

- Python can call R and execute native R packages
- R Console can't find its libraries
- RStudio works as usual with all libraries

Using default R_USER:

- Python is not able call R or execute any code
- R Console is able to find its libraries
- RStudio works as usual with all libraries

I somehow can't see the forest for the trees. I know I have to define the user libraries within R but for now, any change within for R_USER had a direct impact on Python's behaviour. Any ideas out there?

Thanks a lot for any advice!

P.D.: I'm running on Windows 7 64bit. Python 2.7.9 (Anaconda Distribution), R 3.1.3 and rpy2 2.5.6.

Comment: Hi, I have the same question. Did you figure out a way to have rpy2 and Rstudio working after changing R_USER? Thanks. Luis